# Why does this CSV to Python dictionary code give an IndexError?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm writing code to make a global dictionary from a CSV-file in Python. The code doesn't do what I expect.

users.csv

```
name,money_in_pocket
siem,10
bart,10
ivar,10
```

test.py

```
import csv
global users
users = {}   
with open('users.csv', mode='r') as readuserfile:
    readusers = csv.reader(readuserfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readusers)
    for rows in readusers:
        users[rows[0]] = float(rows[1])
```

After running this piece of code, I expect the following to happen in the Shell:

```
>>>print(dict)
{'siem': 10, 'bart': 10, 'ivar': 10}
```

Instead, running test.py throws the next error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ----File "C:\Users\siemd\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in 
>   --------users[rows[0]] = float(rows[1])
>   IndexError: list index out of range

If I understand this right, then the `rows[0]` and `rows[1]` cannot return a value, because they're out of the range of the 'list' (which is a read csv file).
But they should... Right?

Comment: You probably have a blank line at the end of your CSV, or a line somewhere with only one column.

Comment: The users.csv file is exactly the file used in test.py, @DanielRoseman. So every line has 2 columns and there's no last blank line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the length and type of `rows`. Tried your example:

```
$cat t.py
import csv
global users
users = {}
with open('users.csv', mode='r') as readuserfile:
    readusers = csv.reader(readuserfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readusers)
    for rows in readusers:
        users[rows[0]] = float(rows[1])

print users
$cat users.csv
name,money_in_pocket
siem,10
bart,10
ivar,10
$python t.py
{'ivar': 10.0, 'bart': 10.0, 'siem': 10.0}
$
```

Works fine. But if there is a newline at the end it fails:

```
$cat >> users.csv

$python t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 8, in <module>
    users[rows[0]] = float(rows[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
$
```

Adding a simple check helps:

```
$cat t.py
...
    for rows in readusers:
        if len(rows)==2:
          users[rows[0]] = float(rows[1])
...
$python t.py
{'ivar': 10.0, 'bart': 10.0, 'siem': 10.0}
$
```

Comment: Thanks for this in depth answer, @Mandraenke. adding `if len(row)==2:` fixed the problem. The weird thing is that there's _not_ a newline at the end. Checked numerous times... Maybe it got something to do with the Python version. I don't know...